# log shifting \ writing error coming and going

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every now and then, I encounter the following problem.
I use rails 3.2. And sometimes I get this error:

```
log shifting failed. closed stream
log writing failed. closed stream
```

It doesn't stop the flow of the program, but it does stops logging.
How to handle the problem?